# Where are case comments located?

Tags: api, sobject, standard-objects, workbench

I am looking for the case comments object within Workbench, but I am unable to find where the replies are being stored.

I found the main parent comment located within `CommentFeed`, and it also shows the `CommentCount` which reflects the number of replies, those replies however just don't show up.

[image]

Where can I find the replies to the parent comment?

Comment: So the `CaseFeed` object is all of the Chatter Posts associated with that case. There is also the CaseComment Object as well (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm)

Comment: Strange, nothing comes up for me in that object when I am logged in as my API user. I will see if I can query it from the dev console instead. It "sounds" like that's where it would be, just not sure why nothing is showing up.